# How to speedup unittests in laravel which use database migrations?

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have many tests in laravel app.

They make POST/GET requests and check responses.

Every test is performed using DatabaseMigrations trait.

On my laptop it takes about 20 seconds for every test to be finished.

I do not want to write different `repositories` for different types of queries so that I can later mock them (extra work).

May be there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [in memory testing using SQLite](http://ryanstelmat.com/laravel-setting-up-an-in-memory-test-database/):

```
'testing' => [  
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

In this case, migrations and seeders will create data filled tables really quick.

Comment: What are cons of this solution? For example, some tests might fail because of different types of data.

Comment: Avoid running tests on another DB - it may play a bad joke with you